# Cannot Import name 'self' from 'typing'

Tags: python, python-typing

Anybody knows how to fix this problem ?

```
Exception has occurred: ImportError
cannot import name 'self' from 'typing' (C:\Users\Piotr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\typing.py)
  File "C:\Users\Piotr\Downloads\music_bot-main\music_cog.py", line 2, in <module>
    from typing import self
ImportError: cannot import name 'self' from 'typing' (C:\Users\Piotr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\typing.py)
```

I wanted to make a discord bot that could play music but that's the problem that stops me from making it.

Answer (score 8):

Two issues:

1. It's [`typing.Self`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Self), not `typing.self` (not the capitalized `S`), and
2. `typing.Self` was added in Python 3.11, but you're using Python 3.10. To use `Self` in versions prior to 3.11, you can use the [`typing-extensions`](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) distribution, which backports new and experimental type hinting features to older Python versions:

   ```
   from typing_extensions import Self
   ```

Comment: I am currently using Pyton 3.11 but now this is the problem :
TypeError: BotBase.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'