# abstractmethod returns a type of self

Tags: python, inheritance, mypy, python-typing

I'm having some problems with mypy.

I have an abstract class and a class that inherits from it:

```
from __future__ import annotations

from abc import abstractmethod, ABC
from typing import Union


class Base(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def the_method(self, a_class: Union[Base, float, int]) -> None:
        ...

    @abstractmethod
    def other_method(self) -> None:
        ...


class MyClass(Base):
    def __init__(self, something: str = "Hello") -> None:
        self.something = something

    def the_method(self, a_class: Union[MyClass, float, int]) -> None:
        print(a_class)

    def other_method(self) -> None:
        print(self.something)
```

I am aware of the **Liskov substitution principle**. However `MyClass` is a type of `Base` since it inherits from it. But `mypy` still raises an error:

```
main.py:21: error: Argument 1 of "the_method" is incompatible with supertype "Base"; supertype defines the argument type as "Base | float | int"  [override]
main.py:21: note: This violates the Liskov substitution principle
main.py:21: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#incompatible-overrides
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science), especially the section on function types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Base.the_method` accepts `Base`, so subclasses need to accept *at least* `Base` too. If I have a `class Foo(Base)`, that should be accepted. At the moment, it's not accepted by `MyClass.the_method`.

Liskov substitution works in the opposite direction for method parameters and return types - superclasses are OK for parameters, subclasses are OK for return types.

You have lots of options. For example, you could make `MyClass.the_method` accept `Base`

```
class MyClass(Base):
    def the_method(self, a_class: Union[Base, float, int]) -> None:
        ...
```

or (and there's a discussion in the comments about whether this next example also violates LSP ... either way, mypy is overly permissive with this) change `Base` to accept instances of the enclosing class

```
from typing import Self

class Base(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def the_method(self, a_class: Union[Self, float, int]) -> None:
        ...
```

Comment: The solution with `Safe` might satisfy mypy (does it though?), but it breaks the liskov substitution principle. E.g  for `x: Base = MyClass()`, it should be allowed to call `x.the_method()` with any instance of `Base` as argument.

Comment: Is `Self` accepted in your second example? Looks like obvious LSP violation (unsafe upcasting). [Surprisingly, yes](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=616112da89e16037297b08ded5a08b77)

Comment: I wonder if this is related to this horrible code `class A: def foo(self: object) -> None: ...; A.foo(1)` which passes mypy

Comment: @joel no, that shouldn't be related. The surprising behaviour of Self above seems to align with PEP673 definition - it was likely a flaw in the PEP itself. I'll publish this concern on the typing forum, if you don't want to do it yourself - sounds like a big Self design bug.

Comment: yeah it's in the PEP [here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/#use-in-parameter-types)

Comment: @STerliakov it's not specific to `Self`, [I can reproduce it with `TypeVar`](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=9deca7e4c74ee8f415d02308161a3c0e)

Comment: @zvone actually I'm not convinced this does violate LSP, because `Base` does not say you can call `the_method` with a `Base`, it says you can call it with whatever type you have, which you no longer know, having cast it to `Base`, so you can only call `x.the_method(x)`

Comment: Indeed, "same type" doesn't really exist in typing: LSP allows using a subtype whenever its parent is expected. Upcasting **must** be safe: if `T <: U`, then `x: U = T()` must succeed, and it shouldn't break any usage that requires `U` instance.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please add https://stackoverflow.com/a/77247460/2681662 to your answer? So the answer would cover versions before 3.11?

Comment: @joel Yes, `Self` says use any type you have, but that means that the child class does not accept all arguments which the parent class accepts, which breaks LSP. `mypy` has trouble handling this because it has to allow such behaviour on the `self` argument (which is a special case). What I want to say is that `Self` should only be allowed for `self` and for the return value.

Comment: @zvone LSP is about properties of subtypes. That property doesn't have to be that the method accepts a specific type. The property here is that `a_class` must have the same type as the class `the_method` is called on. The property is not that `the_method` accepts `Base`

Comment: @joel This is completely wrong. LSP is exactly about what type of argument a method must accept compared to what type of argument the method of the parent class accepts.

Comment: @zvone I don't reckon we'll reach a conclusion through a comment section, so to avoid headache, I'll leave this thread here. I can continue in chat if you like

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to not accept `a_class` in the `the_method` method signature and instead get it through the `__init__` inside the child class.

This may even be a better option if several methods of your class need `a_class`, then you don't have to pass `a_class` in every single method:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Base(ABC):
    a_class: Base | float

    @abstractmethod
    def the_method(self) -> None:
        ...

    @abstractmethod
    def other_method(self) -> None:
        ...

class MyClass(Base):
    def __init__(self, a_class: MyClass | float, something: str = "Hello") -> None:
        self.a_class = a_class
        self.something = something

    def the_method(self) -> None:
        print(self.a_class)

    def other_method(self) -> None:
        print(self.something)
```

Now the signatures are matched and it follows the Liskov substitution principle.

Inside `the_method` method, you can access it through the `self.`.

- I substituted `float | int` with `float` as they are the same thing basically.

---

If you also define `a_class: MyClass | float` inside the body of the `MyClass`, it's totally fine from the Mypy's point of view, but Pyright complains about it:

```py
class MyClass(Base):
    a_class: MyClass | float

    def __init__(self, a_class: MyClass | float, something: str = "Hello") -> None:
        self.a_class = a_class
        self.something = something

    def the_method(self) -> None:
        print(self.a_class)

    def other_method(self) -> None:
        print(self.something)
```

Pyright's error:

```
"a_class" overrides symbol of same name in class "Base"
  Variable is mutable so its type is invariant
    Override type "MyClass | float" is not the same as base type "Base | float"
```